# Can we catch an exception without catch block?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, try-catch-finally

Suppose I have a `try`-`finally` block without catch block, we throw an exception inside the `try` block. Am I able to catch that exception?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    try {
        throw new IOException("Something went wrong");
    } finally{
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you have there won't compile. You can catch the exception by adding a `catch` block however.

Comment: If you want to catch an exception, then use a `catch` block.

Comment: The question doesn't make any sense :)

Comment: Not without Catch Block .. you have to have a catch block to catch any exception. thats the way java is built

Comment: please clarify why you need to do that, what is the main target behind this question

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Please look at the accepted answer. @Sanjeev

Comment: @SHE that is for all uncaught exceptions and yes it is a work around but in practice it is good if you catch your exceptions at the right place and deal with them instead of depending on a single exception handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You can use an uncaught exception handler. Its responsibility is to catch the exceptions that your program didn't catch, and do something with it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler((thread, thr) -> thr.printStackTrace());
    throw new IOException("Something went wrong");
}
```

[`setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler-java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler-) is a method that will register a handler that will be invoked when an exception has been thrown in any thread and wasn't caught. The above code will print the stacktrace of the throwable handled.

The handler takes as argument the thread where the exception happened and the throwable that was thrown.

You can also have a handler *per thread* by using [`setUncaughtExceptionHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler-java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler-) on a `Thread` instance. This handler would handle all uncaught exceptions thrown from this thread.